# how to pass interface based property in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

```js
export interface Iresumedata {
  shortIntro: string,
    fullIntro: string,
    mob: number,
    email: string,
    profile: any

}
```

[image]

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ResumedataService
} from "../../services/resumedata.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-experience',
  templateUrl: './experience.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./experience.component.scss']
})
export class ExperienceComponent implements OnInit {

  experiencedata: any = [];
  constructor(private resumeservice: ResumedataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resumeservice.getresumedata().subscribe(data => (this.experiencedata = data.experience));
  }

}
```

I am trying to fetch data through service and successfully getting it, but the thing is whenever I am passing property such as `experience` or `profile` based on JSON object, its continuously throwing error like.

> Property 'experience' does not exist on type 'Iresumedata[]'

where `Iresumedata` is my interface, guys how can I remove this error? Kindly take a look, what exactly should I do?

Comment: That's because you are accessing a property from an array not an object.

Comment: so, what exactly what approach should I use

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: You should check what is the returning type of `getresumedata()` method in your service, it is correct that return array instead of an object ? It will be useful if you can also post the `ResumedataService` service to understand better

Comment: ok I'll check thanks for replying

Comment: To reiterate, your service returns an array, not a single instance, just use a for of, or something like it

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these step.

1. Your interface structure should be like

```
    export interface Iresumedata {

      shortIntro: string,
        fullIntro: string,
        mob: number,
        email: string,
        profile ?: any,
        experience ?:any,

    }
```

2. Import `Iresumedata` into your dashboard component

   3. Use it like

```
    this.resumeservice.getresumedata().subscribe(data:Iresumedata=>{ (this.experiencedata = data.experience)});
```

Comment: I don't think that you can inject the resume data interface as you suggest, as far as I can tell from the question the bug is an incorrect implementation of the get resume data method (which isn't shown in the question)